# Laravel 5 session not persisting after user is logged in

Tags: php, session, laravel

I'm having an interesting issue with Laravel 5.

After logging in a user, the logged in status is not persisted across pages. Clearly it has something to do with `Session::`.

The way I'm logging in a user is pretty straight-forward:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password']],
    isset($data['remember_me']) ? TRUE : FALSE))
{
    return redirect()->intended('/');
}
```

A simple `print_r(Session::all());` gives me the following if the user is NOT logged in:

```
Array
(
    [_token] => wV8o75lZnCZ0f6CMMQgdBBM2AxSYjtWisAXx6TgZ
    [flash] => Array
        (
            [old] => Array
                (
                )

            [new] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [_previous] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://localhost/public
        )

)
```

After the user is logged in an redirected to `/` the array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [_token] => wV8o75lZnCZ0f6CMMQgdBBM2AxSYjtWisAXx6TgZ
    [flash] => Array
        (
            [old] => Array
                (
                )

            [new] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [_previous] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://localhost/public/
        )

    [login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc] => 2
)
```

However, after any action that will lead to a page refresh or a redirect, the session status is lost.

My `config/session.php` file looks like so:

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,

];
```

The locally stored file for the session can be written and read.

I've tried using `database` drive instead of file. Same thing happens the `[login_xx] => 2` key/value is lost and I'm logged out.

Since the `Session::` is not completely reset I'm suspecting that I'm not logging in the  user properly or simply doing something that I shouldn't be doing somewhere.

Comment: And `Auth::check()` after the redirect returns `false`?

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, after the initial redirect to `/` it returns true. After any action, it will return `false`, yes.

Comment: Are you using any sort of encryption with your password? Right now it looks like you are attempting to log the user in with a plain text password. Laravel ships with `bcrypt`, and if you are using the Registrar right out of the box, the create method uses `bcrypt`. Try `Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])`

Comment: The password is encrypted by default when using `Auth::` it's actually no recommended to do what you suggested.

Comment: where is `$data['remember_me']` coming from?

Comment: From the view, it's just for the remember me token. I've tried without it too. Same thing.

Comment: @Andrew just a stupid question: is your browser saving cookies? And are you able to login at all?

Comment: @sitilge Yes, it does as far as I can tell. Checked with both php and js. All seems to be in working order...you know, except for the sessions persisting "small" issue.

Comment: @sitilge And yes, I am able to login, but as I said, as soon as a page refresh happens or any other redirect for that matter, the session gets reset.

Comment: Looks alot like just session failure to me. Are you sure the session directory is writeable by the web server? Have you tried other session drivers? You should ideally use Redis or Memcached.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I am absolutely sure the directory is write-able . I've checked it a dozen times so far. I'll try switching Monday to another computer. Maybe there's something wrong with my home machine.

Comment: Have you switched to say the database/redis/memcached driver so you can rule out the filesystem completely? Not as a permanent solution as you say you'd like to stick with the file driver but it'll help discern certain things if it works/fails with other drivers

Comment: @BenSwinburne I have not. I'll try to get around doing that today. I was stupidly busy lately. I will update my question as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: @BenSwinburne Just tried it a minute ago. Same thing. The data is written in the database, but as soon as refresh/redirect happens the `[login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc] => 2` key/value is lost. At this point I can't even begin to guess what's wrong anymore.

Comment: Have you perhaps got some middleware or filters which is causing a problem? Perhaps middleware `guest`? Is this 5.0.x or 5.1? If it's 5.1 did you upgrade from 5 or fresh install?

Comment: @BenSwinburne No middleware, I wasn't using the out-of-the box middle ware, but I've specifically removed every middleware that came with the default installation just now, as in deleted the files, no difference.. It's 5.1.2(LTS), using `php artisan --version` to determine that. I have not upgraded, it's fresh out of the box. I've tried it on my work machine too, which is running Ubuntu, same thing. The `md5` hash is lost.

Comment: Interesting. What's the session lifetime set to? `dd(config('session.lifetime'))`. Do the same with `session.driver` and make sure it's not defaulting to `array` somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80684/discussion-between-ben-swinburne-and-andrew).

Comment: @BenSwinburne `session.lifetime` = 120, `session.driver` = database.

Comment: Hey if you are using database then you should check if the session info are stored on database or not.

Comment: create a simple app with session if you can access session variable across pages then u may have missed some thing while implementing Auth check configuration / model classes and how session are set if user is successfully logged in.

Comment: Can you please provide the HTTP headers in the response right after logging in? It's just a guess but maybe the cookie is set on some different domain. Check that the Set-Cookie domain is the same as the domain you access the application on.

Comment: Session files are stored in "Storage/framework/sessions".  Maybe the problem is due to insufficient permission for the storage folder.

Comment: I answered, if that didn't answer your question, please take the time to comment to my answer and explain how it wasn't. I'd appreciate the feedback; answering takes time away from other things.

Comment: this happens in the production environment or the development environment?

Answer (score 13):

I faced similar issue, I simply called:

```
Session::save();
```

after any add/update/delete to Session storage. So it looked like:

```
$id = Input::get('id');
Session::forget('cart.' .$id);
Session::save();
```

Comment: This fixed the problem for me under laravel 5.3. Before adding `save`, no custom session data is saved to the file, after that everything's just fine. However I just don't understand: `Session::save` is totally missed out in [the doc](https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/session), without which the session is just unusable, why would the laravel team do this?

Comment: This FINALLY solved my issue.

Session::save();
Is required.

Comment: @RohanJetha Session::save() is only required when your script stop by exit or die  function. Then you have to add this function after session define and destroy function.

Comment: @BhavinThummar thank you! I had a `dd()` after an `Auth::attempt()`. The attempt was successful, but the login was never persisted. Removed the dd and it persisted fine!

Comment: @PhilCross , If your problem is solved by understanding, then it is too good.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. Once I removed the various combinations of dd() and print_r() I was using to dump responses for testing purposes and allowed the method to complete and fully render the view, the issue went away and sessions persisted.

Comment: This worked for me (using Laravel 5.1). However, using the return parameter on `print_r()` allows the persistence of the session: `print_r($request->session(), true);`

Comment: This is correct. The sessions are saved at the end of the request lifecycle. So, interrupting the execution will prevent the session from being saved. Use dump() instead of dd() or manually trigger the save with Session::save()

Comment: @spedly.wasted 4 to 5 hours to fix this .but your answer saved me finally

Answer (score 7):

I solved changing

```
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
```

to

```
'cookie' => 'myapp_session',
```

according to laravel the name of the cookie affects every driver

Comment: I also faced a similar problem and resolved the above answer. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216511/session-is-expiring-automatically-in-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Laravel, but on CodeIgniter I save user session in CI's Session Class and Laravel has one too.

I suggest to use the [build-in session](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session) which is more persistent than default $_SESSION - probably it saves user data in database and on each page refresh/change the session is populated again from DB.

When user authenticates, just save its session data like this:

```
Session::put('userData', 'value');
```

...where value could be just a boolean value or an entire object that holds user specific data.

On each page load, get user data from session:

```
$user = Session::get('userData');

if($user->id) echo 'user is logged-in'; //or if($user) - depends on what you store in 'userData' key
else echo 'guest only privilegies';
```

**EDIT:**
I see that you use the Auth Class. My answer is mostly for manual login of the user and it works.
I think that the Auth Class should be doing this by default, but probably you're missing some configuration or there's a bug.

Here's a possible solution (Laravel 4, but it worths a try): http://laravel.io/forum/11-11-2014-authcheck-always-returning-false

#### Update:

As of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545235/laravel-5-session-variables-not-persisting-after-redirects-twitter-oauth?rq=1) you should try to change the driver value from

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')
```

to

```
'driver' => 'file'
```

...also on Laravel's docs you can see that the driver has to be defined like that.

Comment: That link is purple unfortunately :(  . I've google'd everything I could think of for the past 2 days.

Comment: Just do some ``put`` and ``get`` within Session Class and see if the data is still there after page refresh/change. If data is not lost, then it's a problem with Auth Class or something else you're doing in your app.

Comment: Did you try all possible Session Drivers? I would go with "database".

Comment: I did try indeed try with `put` and the values are stored properly, I can in fact retrieve them with no issues. I'll give the database drive a shot too, although I'd rather remain with the file. But in the position I'm at  I can't complain.

Comment: i've updated my answer with a possible solution. i think that might be it :)

Comment: @TanaseButcaru your latest update is incorrect (or unfavourable, let's say. It would technically work) and the wrong way to define the driver. Laravel 5 uses DotEnv to configure settings. The `env()` function will look at a file entitled `.env` for a definition of `SESSION_DRIVER` and use that. In the absence of that definition it will fall back to the second parameter which is in this case `file`

Comment: Actually the last solution worked for me. Every reload/request my session file was being changed. Replacing `"'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER',  '<chosen driver>')"` for `"'driver'=> '<chosen driver>'"`  worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you don't have some sort of a before filter, middleware, or route group that is causing them to be logged out. At least temporarily, search for any Auth::logout() and comment it out.  I have seen this be the problem more than once.

Second, you look like you're doing this call correctly. The third parameter is $login : bool and it defaults to true. This is not your problem, but please change your TRUE and FALSE to true and false to meet with PSR-1/2 standards.

I would have advised that you try another driver, but you have done that and have the same result. This leads me to think that you have some sort of earlier code that is misdirecting to a logout().

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure of 2 things if you are using default laravel's **file session** which you can check if you are using in session.php file.

1. The session directory ie storage/framework/session/ is writable.
2. The routes for logging in maybe (/login) and for checking authentication (maybe /dashboard) are all within the group web

ie.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   Route::get('/home/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getLogin']);
Route::post('/home/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'HomeController@postLogin']);
   Route::get('/home/dashboard', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getDashboard']);
}
```

This worked for me in Laravel 5.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem to and i solve this way.
After `Auth::attemp` or `Auth::login()` dont use `echo, var_dump or dd()` i dont know why but those prevent to keep the session in the browser.

And now is working

```
                public function testLogin(Request $request, $id){

                    $user = Account::find($id);
                    Auth::login($user);

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I have fixed it by changing the Session Driver from
`SESSION_DRIVER=database`
to
`SESSION_DRIVER=file`

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to save like `session()->save()` or `Session::save()`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issues after the user logged in the session is not persistent.
So i found the solution for this.
just change one line in config/session.php file

## Change in this code

'cookie' => env(
'SESSION_COOKIE',
Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
)

## To:

```
'cookie' => env(
    'local_cookies',
    Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
),
```

then clear the caches. it will fix the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

correctedHum... Ensure your machine is setted with **good date and hour**, and equally the other machines on the network who working with.

For exemple in Debian system:

In the command prompt, hit `date` (*you will see the date*), if it's not correct follow these instructions:

1. apt-get install ntp
2. service ntp start
3. date *(normally the date and hour are corrected)*

Answer (score 0):

Use "cookie" driver instead of "file" of session.php (config\session.php\driver). I had a problem with login using "Auth::loginUsingId()" api instead of "Auth::attempt()" api, it destroyed the session for another request.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the target route also uses the middleware StartSession. 
In my "fresh" installation of Laravel 5.2 the "web" middleware group uses it, but the root path (/), which also happens to be the default $redirectTo after login, was outside of it. Huge loss of time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to change the domain setting in the app/config/sessions.php file. I had a different domain written there instead of the one that I was using and naturally it didn't work. Though I don't understand why the framework went ahead and created the session files each time I was reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but it has been fixed now.

It's because of the conflict between sessions in your machine and in your localhost domain. To solve the problem:

First of all check your `config/session.php` file and check this:

```
'domain' => null,
```

after that clear your cookies:

on Firefox, right click -> view page info -> Security -> View Cookies -> Remove all

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem in laravel 5.4, the solution for me was:

In the file /app/Http/Kernel.php, was commented middleware AuthenticateSession by default.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        //\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Only uncommented this line and the session work fine in all routes

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `loginUsingId()` method you should set 'remember' flag to true.

So, instead of doing:

```
loginUsingId(1);
```

You should do

```
loginUsingId(1, true);
```

[See docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check **public/index.php**, see if there are codes before the Laravel codes. After I remove those codes, I can login just fine.

```
<?php
    echo 'hello';
?>

<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */
```

I seems, someone "messed" with my sites, and index.php is the main target for malicious codes

Answer (score 0):

Just add  session start and authenticate middleware to global middleware in `kernel.php` file

Answer (score 0):

> just check then cookie allow false

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false)
```

> In my case I put it as true insted of true, then I changed its into
>   false

Answer (score 0):

I am faced this problem when dealing with the oracle database, and by searching and debugging it is solving by change the `protected $primaryKey = "name in lowercase"`
`public $incrementing = false;`