# Session is expiring automatically in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I am using larvel 5.2 for my application, i didn't used laravel authentication and wrote my own code, at the time of successful login i am storing user name in a session variable and checking this for every request after login. I didn't changed any session settings. My problem is session is expiring in lessthan 3mins and sometimes while login it is showing

> `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:`

remember only sometimes. After refresh the page everything become normal and after login within 3mins session is expiring. My code in routes is as follows,

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if(Session::has('username') && Session::get('username') != ""){
        return view('index');
    }
    else{
        return redirect('login');
    }
});
Route::get('login', function () {
    if(Session::has('username') && Session::get('username') != ""){
        return redirect('/');
    }
    else{
        return view('login');
    }
});
```

My login and session storing as,

```
public function checkme(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    //return $request->all();
    $username = $request->username;
    $password = md5($request->password);

    $admin = Admin::where('username', $username)
                ->where('password', $password)
                ->where('status', 'active')
                ->first();

    if(is_null($admin)){

        Session::flash('Invalid','Invalid Credentials..!');
        return redirect('login');
    }
    else{

        Session::put('username',$admin->username);
        return redirect('/');
    }

}
```

My login form code,

```
<form class="login" method="post" action="login">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<% csrf_token() %>">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required="true" />
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="true" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" />
                </form>
```

Comment: share the part where you putting user in session ?

Comment: @user2486 i updated my question.

Comment: Share you login form snippet

Comment: @PankajMakwana i posted my login form code.

Comment: `<% csrf_token() %>` this will not work in php. Try this `<?=csrf_token()?>` OR `{{csrf_token()}}`

Comment: put `bdf38ec654e79df380f060eaff11ba23`  here : [decrypt](http://www.md5online.org/md5-decrypt.html)

Comment: @PankajMakwana actually i am using angular js due to syntax conflict i used this and no problem with it. It's working fine and i am able to see the token value on inspect element. i used `Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');`

Comment: Why you are not using laravel authentication ?

Comment: @user2486 i have my limitations here.

Comment: @user2486 what is this `bdf38ec654e79df380f060eaff11ba23` about?

Comment: it means you are not secure with `md5`

Comment: @user2486 ok i got your point. once the issue is solved i will change it. and thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution but it seems strange for me.
In `config/session.php`
 i changed this 
`'cookie' => 'laravel_session',` 
to
 `'cookie' => 'myapp_session',` 
I got this suggestion from laracasts click [link here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/session-is-expiring-automatically-in-laravel-52)

I still feeling strange about this, if anyone know the reasons behind the issue please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about `Session::save()` or `session()->save()`

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question; it is better suited as a comment.